# Passing multiple value in ajax using <a> tag, and retrieving a value that was submitted

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

This is a very simple function if one where to use an input tag, unfortunately i have to use a link tag since i'm working with alphabet grouping that would retrieve the values on a different page.

here's a code i found for link tag to hold a value to be submitted to ajax

```
echo '<a onclick="passPagination(\'3\');passLetter(\'S\')">NEXT</a>';
```

i want to call all letters "s" page "3" from the other page.

```
        function passLetter(str)
    {
    if (str=="")
      {
      document.getElementById("retail_group").innerHTML="";
      return;
      } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("retail_group").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","otherpage.php?letter="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }

    function passPagination(str)
    {
    if (str=="")
      {
      document.getElementById("retail_group").innerHTML="";
      return;
      } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
                    document.getElementById("retail_group").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","otherpage.php?pageno="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

also i want to call again the letter that was passed to the otherpage so that i would make it as a reference for my pagination links that is also being hold in this page.
     echo 'NEXT';

i am really at lost here since i am not familiar with link tag and ajax working together, also as you may have noticed i am not also that good with ajax judging from my very long ajax code.

Your help is greatly appreciated, Thank You.

i am really new at ajax. :)

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do. Do you make two different ajax calls on purpose? why not make one call to: "otherpage.php?letter=" + letter + "&pageno=" + pageno ?

Comment: i would love that but how will the parameter be set? also after testing it seems onclick="passPagination(\'3\');passLetter(\'S\')" only sees S and not 3. any idea on this matter? thank you very much.

Comment: lol, any better idea for doing a letter grouping?

Comment: First of all, learn about event handling. Don't use inline event handlers. Read about [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) (for older IEs, you need to use `attachEvent`). [Quirksmode has a great article on advanced event handlers also](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to make a function with multiple arguments:

```
function passPaginationAndLetter(page, letter)
{
if (page=="" || letter == "")
  {
  document.getElementById("retail_group").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
                document.getElementById("retail_group").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","otherpage.php?letter="+letter+"&pageno="+page,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

You can now call this with

`echo '<a onclick="passPaginationAndLetter(\'3\',\'S\')">NEXT</a>';`

The difference is that you are not calling two AJAX methods, just one.

Comment: so regarding the parameter ajax will respectively name it based on what was inside the function(param,param2). thank you. now i have advanced my knowledge in ajax a little. btw do you by chance have any idea on how would i be able to retrieve the value of letter that i passed to otherpage back to this page, since i want to use it for the pagination. Once again thank you very much.

Comment: By the way, it's not "knowledge in Ajax", it's knowledge in Javascript.  You don't need to retrieve the letter, because you already have it inside the function call - where you're setting the `innerHTML` of `retail_group`, you can also operate on `page` and `letter` however you need to.

Comment: so i can get the letter and do this? <a onclick="passPaginationAndLetter(\'3\',$letter)">? Sorry for that i forgot that ajax is javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not pretty sure if i got what you mean, but i guess you want to something like that

```
echo '<a onclick="get(\'S\', '. ($_GET['page'] + 1) .')">NEXT</a>';

function get(letter, page) {
    if (!letter) {
      document.getElementById("retail_group").innerHTML="";
      return;
    }

    if (!page) {
       page = 1;
    }

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        document.getElementById("retail_group").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","otherpage.php?letter=" + letter + "&pageno=" + page,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

if it's really that, don't forget to validate the variables got from $_GET before use that, i just didn't because it's not the point...

Comment: will ajax respectively identify the input as letter, and page? Thank you for this. will give this a try. on a later note, do you by chance know how to retrieve the value of letter that was passed on the otherpage? Thank You :) BTW why get(param,param2) not just normal (param,param2)?

Comment: It's just you pass to the function on this order, first the letter and after the page... on the other page you'll use `$page = $_GET['page'];` and `$letter = $_GET['letter'];` after you can use both values on the link, just like i put the page. and finally it's `get(param, param2)` because get is the name of the function.

Comment: thank you for that explanation, i have solve this problem already, ironically another one pop out.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

**html**

```
<a href="#" id="previous" onclick="previous(); return false;">PREVIOUS</a><a href="#" id="next" onclick="next(); return false;">NEXT</a>
```

**javascript**

```
var current = {
    page: 0,
    letter: a
};

function ajax(url) {
    var xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest || new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(xmlhttp) {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementByI("retail_group").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function next() {
    ajax("otherpage.php?letter=" + current.letter + "&pageno=" + (++current.page));
}

function previous() {
    ajax("otherpage.php?letter=" + current.letter + "&pageno=" + (--current.page));
}
```

This code is not complete of course, it doesn't check for the max/min values of the pages, and there's no way of replace the letter, but it should point you in the right direction.